# Neo4j path query / sorting properties in path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Pretty simple shortest path query on the Movies data set:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p1:Person)-[*0..15]-(p2:Person)) WHERE toLower(p1.name) = toLower('Halle Berry') AND toLower(p2.name) = toLower('Tom Hanks') 
RETURN relationships(path) AS relationships, nodes(path) AS nodes
```

How can I sort the roles array? I.e. on this particular movie, they had a bunch of roles. I can sort it on the app side, but would be nice to do it on the Neo side. When it comes to Nodes, I've been doing this with UNWIND, but that doesn't seem to work on path properties.

Comment: what is your sample expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the elements of the path and get the attributes one at a time. It is quite tedious but it gets the work done.

elements[index] is starting node; elements[index+1] is relationship and elements[index+2] is the ending node.
ID(node) is the node id and type(node) is the relationship type

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p1:Person)-[*0..15]-(p2:Person)) 
WHERE toLower(p1.name) = toLower('Halle Berry') AND toLower(p2.name) = toLower('Tom Hanks') 
WITH apoc.path.elements(path) AS elements, nodes(path) AS nodes
UNWIND range(0, size(elements)-2) AS index
WITH nodes, elements, index WHERE index %2 = 0
WITH nodes, ID(elements[index]) AS start, ID(elements[index+1]) AS identity, ID(elements[index+2]) AS end, type(elements[index+1]) as type, elements[index+1] as roles
UNWIND roles as role
WITH nodes, start, end, identity, type, apoc.coll.sort(role.roles) as roles
RETURN collect({start: start, end: end, identity: identity, type: type, properties: {roles: roles}}) as relationships, nodes

RESULT:
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"relationships"                                                       │"nodes"                                                               │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"identity":139,"start":106,"end":105,"type":"ACTED_IN","properties":│[{"name":"Halle Berry","born":1966},{"title":"Cloud Atlas","tagline":"│
│{"roles":["Jocasta Ayrs","Luisa Rey","Meronym","Ovid"]}},{"identity":1│Everything is connected","released":2012},{"name":"Tom Hanks","born":1│
│37,"start":105,"end":71,"type":"ACTED_IN","properties":{"roles":["Derm│956}]                                                                 │
│ot Hoggins","Dr. Henry Goose","Isaac Sachs","Zachry"]}}]              │                                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

====EDITED===
You can UNWIND the roles then sort it.  Lastly, collect them again as a list of dictionaries.

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p1:Person)-[*0..15]-(p2:Person)) 
WHERE toLower(p1.name) = toLower('Halle Berry') AND toLower(p2.name) = toLower('Tom Hanks') 
WITH relationships(path) AS relationships, nodes(path) AS nodes
UNWIND relationships as role
WITH apoc.coll.sort(role.roles) as roles, nodes 
RETURN collect({roles: roles}) as relationships, nodes

RESULT:
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"relationships"                                                       │"nodes"                                                               │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"roles":["Jocasta Ayrs","Luisa Rey","Meronym","Ovid"]},{"roles":["De│[{"name":"Halle Berry","born":1966},{"title":"Cloud Atlas","tagline":"│
│rmot Hoggins","Dr. Henry Goose","Isaac Sachs","Zachry"]}]             │Everything is connected","released":2012},{"name":"Tom Hanks","born":1│
│                                                                      │956}]                                                                 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: if you want to sort it by last name, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I had gotten this far myself actually, but notice that if you go to table mode, the relationships have been lost :(. I tried using apoc.create.relationship to put it back together, but couldn't figure out how to get the start node and the end node. In this case there are just 2 people and 1 movie, but if you pick something better, say Al Pacino -> Kevin Bacon, you'll get more paths, so you can't exactly do nodes[0], nodes[1], etc. You'll notice in the original query, the relationship has all the start and end nodes that have been lost by the unwind.

Comment: hi, the new query is just about working, thanks! I did find a minor issue, if you do Tom Cruise -> Tom Hanks, you run into relationships where there is no roles property, so it throws an error on the sort, I did sort of fix it to be apoc.coll.sort(coalesce(role.roles, [])) which fixes the error, but creates an empty roles array, is there a way to avoid creating the roles array if not there? I was looking for some kind of if/else. Was trying to wrap the call in apoc.when too but no luck...

Comment: I guess I'll just do CASE WHEN role.roles IS NOT NULL THEN apoc.coll.sort(role.roles) ELSE role.roles END as roles. Thanks again! Upvoted everywhere :).

Comment: Lol.. it looked like it was working in the browser, but when I went to implement it on the Java side, it's getting read in as a node vs. a relationship. Might just be easier to go back to the original query and sort the roles in the app :).